# how to search a property in neo4j that isn't valid json

Tags: neo4j, cypher, neo4j-apoc

I inherited this neo4j DB that has people nodes that look like this:

```
{
  "identity": 1124565178,
  "labels": [
    "Person"
  ],
  "properties": {
    "id": "e5d4a01d-aff5-41c9-95e2-8928b526ddf8",
    "emails": "[{address=username1@hotmail.com, type=personal}, {address=username2@gmail.com, type=personal}]",
    ..
  },
  "elementId": "1124565178"
}
```

I noticed that the `emails` property is not even valid json, so when I run this

```
MATCH (person:Person {id: '5eadad9a-4f99-4cd4-af71-c6e3b6f5d22c'}) return apoc.convert.fromJsonList(person.emails)
```

I get this error

> Failed to invoke function `apoc.convert.fromJsonList`: Caused by: com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParseException: Unexpected character ('=' (code 61)): was expecting a colon to separate field name and value
> at [Source: (String)"[{address=zslayback@gmail.com, type=personal}, {address=zachary@discoverpraxis.com, type=professional}]"; line: 1, column: 11]

### question

Assuming that I cannot modify the structure of the person node, how can I search for a person node that has the email `username1@hotmail.com`?

Answer (score 1):

You can use a simple `CONTAINS` query in the `WHERE` clause:

```
MATCH (p:Person)
WHERE p.emails CONTAINS 'username1@hotmail.com'
RETURN p
```